# Error al comprobar si una tabla esta vacía en PHP

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, web

estoy intentando comprobar si una tabla esta vacía para que le devuelva al usuario un texto u otro, lo estoy haciendo con la función **num_rows**, pero no da resultados. Por aquí os dejo el código:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contraseña";

$result = $db->prepare($query);

if ($query->num_rows == 0) { 
    echo "Tabla vacia<br>";
    echo "<a href='index.php'>Volver</a>";
} else {
    echo "Hay algún dato en la tabla"
}
```

¿Alguien sabe como se puede solucionar?

Comment: Te diría que metas todo en un try{}catch para ver si te está dando alguna excepción al hacer la consulta. Suena muy raro una tabla `contraseña` por la ñ. Quizás no te coje bien ese nombre? A lo mejor hay que poner el nombre de la tabla entre comillas simple...

Answer (score 1):

Yo haría algo así:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contraseña";

$result = $db->query($query)->fetch_row()[0];

if ($result == 0) { 
    echo "Tabla vacia<br>";
    echo "<a href='index.php'>Volver</a>";
} else {
    echo "Hay algún dato en la tabla"
}
```

Comment: He implementado lo que me has dicho, pero me devuelve este error: **Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_row()**

Comment: Ah, eso es porque estás usando PDO. Conéctate por msyqli y lo resuelves con: `$db=new mysqli('localhost','root','','database');`

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_row()

Indica claramente que estás usando PDO, y `fetch_row` no es un método de PDO sino de mysqli.

Por otra parte, si se trata de comprobar si la tabla está vacía o no, lo mejor es una consulta del tipo `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Aparte de eso, solamente estás preparando la consulta con `prepare`, pero no la estás ejecutando con `execute()`. Si no ejecutas, no tendrás jamás resultados.

Así debería funcionar:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM contraseña";
$result = $db->prepare($query)->execute();
$mData = $result->fetchColumn();
echo $mData == 0 ? 'Tabla vacía <br /><href="index.php">Volver</a>' : 'Hay algún dato en la tabla';
```

#### Recomendación

Evita usar `ñ` y acentos en nombres de tablas, columnas, o en variables. Estos caracteres pueden romper el código si no tienes bien configurada la codificación, tanto en PHP, en el HTML y en el objeto de conexión a la base de datos.